# Count php query database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have to make a list of games based on the most votes. 
I must then use the count by the query to my db.Ho tried the code below but nothing happens. Help me

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","blog");
            // Check connection
            if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
            }

            $result = mysql_query($con,"SELECT COUNT(nomeGioco) FROM voto");


            mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: You are not printing anything. Try `var_dump($result);`

Comment: This code is incomplete, so go back to php.net and look at the database examples again.

Comment: Show me some example of code. Please

Comment: You're mixing mysql_ with mysqli_. Change `mysql_query` to `mysqli_query`, then actually echo out $result

Comment: What is the structure of your table? If you wish to make a list of games based on votes, you probably need `GROUP BY`.

Comment: I don't know how i have to do. I want order by the most voted

Comment: What is the structure of your table?

Comment: two simple columns: name and game name User (voting). I have to sort the games according to the most voted and maybe put beside the number of votes of each game

Comment: ^ So, three columns then?

Comment: only two columns. NameGames and NameUser

Comment: Ah, then a game that is voted for five times needs to have its name in the `NameGame` column five times - an excessive amount of duplication. It would be better to have three tables - one for games, one for users, and one for votes. You can then just use foreign keys from the vote table to users and games.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'd like to get a list of game names, along with the number of times that that name appears in the table, you'll want to start with the following query:

```
SELECT nomeGioco, COUNT(nomeGioco) num_count 
    FROM voto 
    GROUP BY nomeGioco 
    ORDER BY num_count DESC
```

To break it down a little, GROUP BY will aggregate the rows based on the 'nomeGioco' column, and "ORDER BY column DESC" will sort your rows by `num_count` in descending order (leaving the games occurring the most in the table at the top).

You can then use `mysqli_fetch_all` to get all of the results from that results object, like so:

```
$query = 'SELECT nomeGioco, COUNT(nomeGioco) num_count '
        . 'FROM voto '
        . 'GROUP BY nomeGioco '
        . 'ORDER BY num_count DESC';

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","blog");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

$contents = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

mysqli_free_result($result);
mysqli_close($con);

// The contents of the query
var_dump($contents);

// Go through each row and append them to a string to output in HTML
$toHTML = '';
if(is_array($contents)) {
    foreach($contents as $row) {
        $toHTML .= $row['nomeGioco'] . ': ' . $row['num_count'] . ' votes<br />';
    }
}

echo $toHTML;
```

Comment: Great answer, though the OP is suggesting - I think - to add a vote count column to this table. That would be somewhat better than repeating the game name for each vote (though it would be even better, in my view, to have a separate voting table, so that users cannot vote twice - insofar as you can check that sort of thing in a web application).

Comment: Ah no, he/she really does want to repeat `nomeGioco` for each vote for a game!

Comment: I don't undestand how i can show the list. This code give me an array, can you explain me?

Comment: @user3766806: just use a `foreach($contents as $row)` loop, and you can then get the columns from `$row`.

Comment: Sorry but i don't know how do. Can you show me?

Comment: @user3766806 - What halfer said. I've updated my answer to do just that.

Answer (score -1):

make query

```
$con = New mysqli("localhost","root","","blog");
if (!$conn)
{
die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_error());
}
$query = $con->query("SELECT COUNT(`nomeGioco`) FROM `voto`");
$result = $query->fetch_assoc();
echo $result['COUNT(nomeGioco)'];
$con->close;
```